# carousel next / prev buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the following lightbox carousel from https://codepen.io/webcane/pen/lHGJf
Things was working fine until i tried the previous and next button on the carousel doesn't work (Left and Right button on keyboard do work though).

```
  // Hidden gallery
  /* activate the carousel */
  $("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

  /* change modal title when slide changes */
  $("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
    $(".modal-title")
    .html($(this)
    .find(".active img")
    .attr("title"));
  });

  /* when clicking a thumbnail */
  $(".row .service-icon").click(function() {
    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
    var title = $(".modal-title");

    content.empty();  
    title.empty();

    var id = this.id;  
    var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
    var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
    var active = repoCopy.first();

    active.addClass("active");
    title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
    content.append(repoCopy);

    // show the modal
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
  });
```

After looking at the rest of my js file, I discovered that the following code that came along with the theme was affecting the buttons, as the carousel buttons works fine after i commented out this block of code.

```
// Smooth scroll on page hash links
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').on('click', function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          if (target.length) {

              var top_space = 0;

              if( $('#header').length ) {
                top_space = $('#header').outerHeight();
              }

              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top - top_space
              }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

              if ( $(this).parents('.nav-menu').length ) {
                $('.nav-menu .menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('menu-active');
              }

              if ( $('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active') ) {
                  $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
                  $('#mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
                  $('#mobile-body-overly').fadeOut();
              }

              return false;
          }
      }
  });
```

Below is the html for my carousel buttons. I am guessing that the smooth scrolling code is picking up on the **href="#modal-carousel"** causing it not to work.

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Is there any workaround to this so that I can have both features working together?

Comment: I pasted the smooth scroll code in the pen , but the left and right buttons are still working. I even ensured that the smooth scroll code is executed by placing debugger statement. Can you comment out specific parts one after another like first comment out : if( $('#header').length ) { //code } part and then others and arrive at what specific block of code is causing issues. Please comment the block identified by you as troublemaker.

Comment: @Dhyey Ok i did what u said. Seems like **return false;** is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by adding

```
:not([href="#modal-carousel"])
```

to

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])')
```

so that it would ignore **#modal-carousel**